# How to get the node config in html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-config

I have a node config according to the environment. https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config

default.json

```
{
  "server": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "protocol": "http",
    "port": 9011
  }
}
```

I want to get this in the `index.html` inside `<script>` tag. Does anyone know what is the way to do this ?

I am able to get this config in js file like below

app.js

```
var config = require('config');
console.log(config.server.host);
```

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have url of another server in index.html, as of now it is hard coded. I want it should be picked from config file. It sends the request from this server to the another server

Comment: you could add a server side rendering tool...what stack are you using?

Comment: I am using nodejs , express framework. What do you mean by "server side rendering tool" you mean react ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a maintainer of `node-config`. In a complex app you'll probably have some secrets you want only visible on the backend, and some values you want to share with the frontend.

Put all values you want to share with the frontend under `frontend` config key.

Then create an `express` route which serves the `frontend` config at `/config.js`:

```js
router.get('/config.js', _configjs);
// Cache the config, don't recompute it on every request
var configJavascript = 'window.CONFIG='+JSON.stringify(config.get('frontend'));
function _configjs (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
  // Last modified now
  res.setHeader('Last-Modified', (new Date()).toUTCString());
  // Cache the config for 5 minutes
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age='+(60*5));
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(configJavascript);
}
```

Now after loading `/config.js` from the frontend, you can access the frontend configuration through the

Answer (score 1):

Make an ajax call to app.js file and get your config files data and use inside index.html file